# My C-based program is crashing, allocating too much memory

Tags: c

I'm reading a text file with coordinates and values and building an NxM table. The problem is that there is a 10^5 x 10^5 file, and I'm allocating space for this huge table. The program won't run - it just stops. Is there any way more efficient to allocate this space, or save values in a different way?

My program runs fine until the file is too big.

Comment: Could you read the file by parts?

Comment: Can you work with a sparse matrix?

Comment: which platform? On POSIX and a 64 bit machine, you can mmap() a file of this size.

Comment: It all depends on what are you doing with that data...

Comment: We need more information about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

Use mmap [Memory mapping and file I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306970/memory-mapping-and-file-i-o/2307143#2307143)

Anytime you are reading a binary file and not intending to extend it, mmap is almost always a better option.